# HTML5 Video and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm using html5 tag "video". How can I find out how much the video loading bar is filled, using JavaScript? (maybe in percent, or at least the current state of downloading and the full size of a file are necessary.

Comment: DON'T SHOUT. WE CAN HEAR YOU.

Comment: I think this previous answer may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182578/5922436