# Is there a way to indicate audio download progress/buffer when using Howler.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

I'm using [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0) and trying to accomplish something like this:

[image: download with buffer]

However, Howler doesn't seem to have support for [audio "progress" events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded). Anybody know how I could work around this?

Comment: Any resolve to this issue?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to bind to Howler's non-public API to achieve this, at least until this feature is implemented (if ever).

```
const audio = new Howl({
  src: 'https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/rave_digger.webm',
  html5: true,
  preload: false,
});

const handleLoad = () => {
  const node = audio._sounds[0]._node;
  // const node:HTMLAudioElement = (audio as any)._sounds[0]._node; // For Typescript
  node.addEventListener('progress', () => {
    const duration = audio.duration();

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges#Creating_our_own_Buffering_Feedback
    if (duration > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < node.buffered.length; i++) {
        if (node.buffered.start(node.buffered.length - 1 - i) < node.currentTime) {
          const bufferProgress = (node.buffered.end(node.buffered.length - 1 - i) / duration) * 100;
          // do what you will with it. I.E - store.set({ bufferProgress });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

audio.on('load', handleLoad);
```

Original answer can be found [here](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/752#issuecomment-372083163) in [goldfire/howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js)