# Howler.js get HTMLMediaElement

Tags: howler.js

is there a way to access the HTMLMediaElement from a Howler.js sound?
I need the HTMLMediaElement for the WebAudioAPI.

Current Code:

```js
this.audio = new Howl({
    src: this.url
})
```

Comment: Howler.js is an abstraction built on top of the Web Audio API and HTML5 Audio. Is there a reason why you're not just using the Web Audio API directly?

Comment: @Julia I cannot use the Web Audio API directly because i need to get the source of the sound, and i need a HTMLMediaElement for that.
let source = this.context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me still looking:

```
var node = audio._sounds[0]._node
//node is an HTMLAudioElement
```

Found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769535/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-audio-download-progress-buffer-when-using-howler-js).