# How to get current percentage of segment loaded in HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I have a video with Dash in HTML5. I need to get the percentage of the current loading segment, every time the video stops for loading (buffering/seeking), percentage start's to grow from 0 to 100. If percentage is in 100% is because the segment has loaded and can continue playing. There's any way to do this?

This is not the same question as [HTML5 Video - Percentage Loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded). I don't need the percentage of the whole loaded video. I need just the percentage of a specific segment. A great example of this could be the Netflix player in Chromecast (Player shows a percentage every time the video stops for loading new segments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video - Percentage Loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded)

Comment: Mr Geek, it's not a duplicate. Are different questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not exposed anywhere with the standard [`Media` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement), though using the [`MediaSource` API](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) you may be able to retrieve more information.

At a guess that's what Netflix are using, in conjunction with [EME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions))