# How to get file size of downloading video to show loading process, like 1.2mb/3mb in js?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

video.buffered, progress, loadeddata not have any information about size of downloaded part.

We have native js, html5 video and standard mp4 files
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Without code it's hard to help diagnose your problem. But perhaps this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video - Percentage Loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded)